# outer shadow effect to textfield in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

while i am trying to implement a round edge to textfield at login screen to my application when i gave shadow effect to it using Quartzcore framework, white rectangular edges comes to the front.[image]

Ihave written below code in viewDidLoad in viewcontroller.m file :-

```
   txt_PhoneNo.layer.cornerRadius = 14;
    txt_PhoneNo.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    [txt_PhoneNo.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
txt_PhoneNo.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        txt_PhoneNo.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4.0f,4.0f);
        txt_PhoneNo.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        txt_PhoneNo.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
        txt_PhoneNo.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

How to remove these white edges from my textfield? I am new to iOS development.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a couple of view in the same places, the textField with its cornerRadius, and another beheind it, to show the shadow. You could try with  txt_PhoneNo.layer.masksToBounds = YES; the border will be ok, but the shadow will disappear. If you give me more info about how you are creating your view I can give you more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the border style before changing layers

```
[_txt_PhoneNo setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

This will work. :)

Comment: It works but have to do some extra work to have the desired result. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in two ways:-

1) Inside your Interface builder ->Attribute Inspector-> Border Style->None:-
[image]

2) If you want to do programmatically then follow @Rashad answer.

Comment: i have tried that but this results in disappearance of the shadow of textfield